# Shopify extract orders + marketing action

Tags: shopify

I need to extract all of our orders from a Shopify shop in order to analyze them. When I check the shops backend, I can see if and where the order is coming from (ppc, organic).

Downloading the excel files, this information is missing.
Looking at the API documentation, I can find an object called marketingEvent, which has (i) a marketing_channel and (ii) a paid flag:

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/marketingevent#properties

but I'm not sure if this is what I am looking for and how a marketingEvent object is related to an order.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it seems like you are discussing about [Conversion Summary](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Discussion/Download-conversion-data-with-order-export/m-p/236371). However, it is not possible to export this data with Orders Export as per this forum post. HOwever, if you have a look at [API reference for Orders](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order), there are few properties that may help you.

- client_details
- landing_site
- referring_site

**client_details** will allow you to see the details like broswer and locale.

**landing_site** will allow you to see the the additional UTM etc parameters that may provide you the additional information.

**referring_site** will define if it was a direct visit or some site that referred visitor to your store.

For more information on Conversion tracking have a look at [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/conversion-summary).

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the GraphQL documentation, you'll find all the answers in there.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/object/marketingevent

Comment: Hi, not sure how this helps. This is only another description of the marketing event. I still don't know how the marketing event is connected to a particular order.